# How to obtain Bio2RDF resource using SPARQL query?

Tags: resources, sparql, rdf, semantic-web

I am working with Bio2RDF biological database and would like to get resource URL for Novobiocin which is [http://bio2rdf.org/drugbank:DB01051 ] using SPARQL query.Using  yasgui.org I selected http://drugbank.bio2rdf.org/sparql service and executed the following query:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

SELECT ?resource WHERE { ?resource dcterms:identifier "drugbank:DB01051"}
```

However, It did not retrieve the result. Could you tell me why it does not work, please ?

Comment: Literals are often typed or sometimes have a language tag. In your case, it's of type `xsd:string`, thus, 
`SELECT ?resource WHERE { ?resource dcterms:identifier "drugbank:DB01051"^^xsd:string .} ` should work.

Comment: Yes I got it and  it works! Thank you so much @AKSW